# How to renew your self-signed certificate p12 with Flash Builder

Tags: android, flash, ssl

I have been using a self-signed certificate (generated using Adobe Flash Builder 4.7) for my Android app. The app is live on Google Play market but the certificate is going to expire soon, and I know if I create new certificate and update my app, existing Android users will not be able to auto-update the app (as the App's Signature has been changed).
I would like to know how can we re-new the self-signed Certificate .p12 with Flash Builder?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing my research about the self-signed certificate created by Adobe Flash Builder , I realized that was my mistake to think that the certificate would expire soon. I doubled check the expiration date of my self-signed certificate and the date was set to 35 years after I generated it using flash builder 4.7 (which is very safe).

For anyone who wants to check the self-signed .p12 expiration date you follow the instruction from this link:
http://bsdsupport.org/how-do-i-determine-the-expiration-date-of-a-p12- certificate/